# Low RMSE, MSE and a good plot of pred and true values but both R^2 and adjusted r^2 are negative. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: time-series, python, scoring-rules

I'm developing a code to predict how many bikes will arrive at a given station.

The issue is that I'm having a hard time interpreting my metrics:

On the one hand, it looks like I have a good MSE and a good RMSE, but adjusted r^2 and r^2, both negative, telling me that my model has a worse fit than a horizontal line. However, my plot(log=True) also indicates that I have relatively good predictions. What do you think might be happening for me to have both R^2 and an adjusted r^2 negative?

```
MSE 0.026319652524120617
RMSE 0.16223332741493227
R^2 -0.3523394531142525
Adjusted R^2 -0.35234760060098713
```

[image]

For this, I am modeling a time series with the following code:

```
X = df.drop('next_count',axis=1)
y = df[['next_count']]

#split the data
tscv = TimeSeriesSplit(n_splits=5)

for train_index, val_index in tscv.split(X):
  X_train, X_test = X.iloc[train_index], X.iloc[val_index]
  y_train, y_test = y.iloc[train_index], y.iloc[val_index]
  y_train = y_train.values.ravel()
  y_test = y_test.values.ravel()


  #scaling
  scaler = MinMaxScaler()
  scaled_train = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
  scaled_test = scaler.transform(X_test)

  #build the model
  model = ZeroInflatedRegressor(
      classifier=DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=0),
      regressor=DecisionTreeRegressor(random_state=0))
  model.fit(scaled_train, y_train)


  #Predict output for scaled_test (unseen data)
  y_pred = model.predict(scaled_test)
```

Comment: How do you define $R^2$?

Comment: @RichardHardy `r2 = r2_score(y_test, y_pred)` and `Adj_r2 = 1 - (1-r2_score(y_test, y_pred)) * (len(y)-1)/(len(y)-X.shape[1]-1)`

Comment: This is Python code but what I am interested in is the mathematical definition. Basically, I am wondering how a square can be negative.